# Node is hanging on mongoose action

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

So I am working on an app with Mongoose and Node. Whenever I try to use postman to get `/api/users` or post `/api/users/name/name/email/test` it just hangs. I have confirmed it is connecting to the database, the `app.listen()` is inside of `db.once('open')`

Here is my model.js

```js
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema   = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  first_name : String,
  last_name  : String,
  email      : {
             type   : String,
             unique : true
  },
  password   : String,
  age        : String,
  address    : String,
  phoneNumber: String,
  gender     : String,
  preferred  : String,
  alerts     : Array
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

Here is my controller.js

```js
const User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = {

  getAllUsers: (req, res) => {
    User.find({}, (err, user) => {
      if(err) {res.send(err)}
      console.log('test');
      res.status(200).json(user);
    });
  },

  createUser: (req, res) => {
    var newUser = new User();
    newUser.first_name = req.params.fn;
    newUser.last_name  = req.params.ln;
    newUser.email      = req.params.em;
    newUser.password   = req.params.pw;
    newUser.save((err, user) => {
      if(err){res.send(err)}
      console.log(newUser.first_name + ' Created');
      res.json(user);
      mongoose.connection.close();
    });
  },

  readUser: (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, (err, user) => {
      if(err){res.send(err)}
      res.json(user)
    });
  },

  updateUser: (req, res) => {
    User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, req.body, {new: true}, (err, user) => {
      if(err){res.send(err)}
      res.json(user);
    });
  },

  removeUser: (req, res) => {
    User.remove({_id: req.params.id}, (err, user) => {
      if(err){res.send(err)}
      res.json("User was succesfully deleted");
    });
  }
}
```

Here is my routes.js

```js
const express = require('express'),
      router  = express.Router(),
      apiController     = require('./controllers/api.controller'    ),
      mainController    = require('./controllers/main.controller'   ),
      profileController = require('./controllers/profile.controller'),
      adminController   = require('./controllers/admin.controller'  );

module.exports = router;

//Handled by apiController
router.get('/api/users', apiController.getAllUsers);
router.post('/api/:fn/:ln/:em/:pw/', apiController.createUser);

router.route('/api/:id')
      .get(apiController.readUser)
      .put(apiController.updateUser)
      .delete(apiController.removeUser);
```

Comment: You are not sending the response correctly when there is no error, use this res.status(200).send(data);

Comment: Just tried and updated still not working. It isn't even logging the `Test` from `console.log()` before it.

Comment: Remove `mongoose.connection.close()` in `createUser`, and also remove `useMongoClient` in your connection setup if you happen to be setting that option.

Comment: That worked, but now I am getting  `node:2698) DeprecationWarning: open() is deprecated in mongoose >= 4.11.0, use openUri() instead, or set the useMongoClient option if using connect() or createConnection()
Db.prototype.authenticate method will no longer be available in the next major release 3.x as MongoDB 3.6 will only allow auth against users in the admin db and will no longer allow multiple credentials on a socket. Please authenticate using MongoClient.connect with auth credentials.`

Comment: That warning is just a warning. If it's the only thing you're seeing right now, it's working. Just know you'll have to update mongoose at some point in the future if you expect to upgrade to mongo `3.6` or higher.